# Is there any way to execute Function from one page to another page in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I have Queue System with 3 pages:
1- add queue no (Page 1).
2- remove(done) queue (Page 2).
3- Customer Sorting queue (Page 3).
how to execute function(in page 3) when only i add or remove from page(1,2).

please help,
 thanks.

example 
page 3

```html
page3.ts

    public test() {
      alert('view this message in page 3 when click button in page 1');
      };
```

page 1

```html
page1.html
 <button type="button"  (click)='test()'>View in page 3</button>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, share your code so that community can help you

Comment: No body can answer

Comment: You have to share your code. No body is going to write everything for you. Try something, atleast share the components

Comment: if i know the code i will not ask!!.